# No water in bathroom after well pump replacment

Tags: water

After replacing  the well pump, one bathroom has no water.

The house Has water with good pressure  except one bathroom, no water in the shower or the sink, but the toilet in that bathroom does have water.

Comment: Cinda,  more  info will help to get an informed answer. Use the edit button to add info. Where there problems that led to the well pump being replaced? What were they?   Add anything you can think of. Who did the work, did all valves closed get re-opened?

Comment: If that was the first faucet(s) tested after replacement they be plugged with debris , rust scale, bits of Teflon tape,  but if everything else is working check the lines funny though because hot and cold don’t take the same path unless on a separate water heater.